# 'bool' object is not subscriptable - Keras

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras

I am currently involved in a deep learning project, which I need to evaluate using sensitivity and specificity metrics, which is not included in keras out-of-the-box.

I have implemented the sensitivity function as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K

def sensitivity(y, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0
    for i in range(5):
        true = (y == i)
        preds = (y_pred == i)
        print(preds)
        TP += K.sum(preds[true == 1])
        FP += K.sum(true[np.invert(preds) == 1])
        TN += K.sum(np.invert(preds)[true == 1])
        FN += K.sum(true[preds == 0])
    return TP / (TP + FN)
```

This works fine by its own. However, when I try to use it when compiling a model, I get the error "'bool' object is not subscriptable."

How can I work around this?

The code for compilation and the full error message is included below. Thank you!
EDIT: By following the reply below and some research, I was able to fix the code, which I have pasted at the bottom of the post. When compiling models in Keras, it is evaluated by either Theano or TensorFlow, and you can therefore not use Numpy commands to make your own metrics.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

model = VGG16(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=10)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy', sensitivity])
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-46c5d210c7ea> in <module>()
     9 model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
     10               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
---> 11               metrics=['accuracy', sensitivity])

/home/USER/Documents/deep_learning/custom_metrics/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    449  output_metrics = nested_metrics[i]
    450  output_weighted_metrics = nested_weighted_metrics[i]
--> 451  handle_metrics(output_metrics)
    452  handle_metrics(output_weighted_metrics, weights=weights)
    453 

/home/USER/Documents/deep_learning/custom_metrics/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in handle_metrics(metrics, weights)
    418  metric_result = weighted_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred,
    419  weights=weights,
--> 420  mask=masks[i])
    421 
    422  # Append to self.metrics_names, self.metric_tensors,

/home/USER/Documents/deep_learning/custom_metrics/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
    402  """
    403  # score_array has ndim >= 2
--> 404  score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    405  if mask is not None:
    406       # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano

<ipython-input-18-caa661fb93ac> in sensitivity(y, y_pred)
     11  preds = (y_pred == i)
     12  print(preds)
---> 13  TP += K.sum(preds[true == 1])
     14  FP += K.sum(true[np.invert(preds) == 1])
     15  TN += K.sum(np.invert(preds)[true == 1])

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

def sensitivity(y, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0
    for i in range(5):
        true = K.equal(y, i)
        preds = K.equal(y_pred, i)
        TP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(~preds, True)), 'int32'))
        TN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(~preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(preds, False)), 'int32'))
    return TP / (TP + FN)
```

Comment: These are TensorFlow tensors, not NumPy arrays, so you have to work differently with them. Replace things like `true = (y == i)` with `true = K.equal(y, i)`. `preds[true == 1]` would be `tf.boolean_mask(preds, tf.equal(true, 1))` or `tf.gather(preds, tf.where(tf.equal(true, 1))[:, 0])` with TensorFlow, I'm not sure how you'd do it with pure Keras backend. `np.invert(preds)` would be `tf.bitwise.invert(preds)` with TensorFlow or just `~preds`.